# Can an adult distribute pornography made when they themselves were underage?

Tags: united-states, minor, pornography

My wife and I made a sex tape about seven years ago, at which time she may or may not have been underage. We just re-found it, and wondered whether it would be technically legal to show it to friends or even possess it ourselves, under United States law.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If* she was underage at the time then the making, possession and distribution of the video is a crime irrespective of how old she is now.

See https://www.justice.gov/criminal-ceos/citizens-guide-us-federal-law-child-pornography

Comment: Thank you for your help. Would you mind citing a source or explaining how you know this information?